# Retrieve Values from Dictionary inside NSDictionary in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

How can I retrieve values from the JSON below?

```
"ItemID": 115,
  "Name": "Test Items for Receive",
  "Description": "Recevive",
  "ItemCode": "AAA-RC-IT1",
  "Quantity":9000,
  "WarehouseLocationID": 560,
  "TransactionDate": "\/Date(-62135596800000+0530)\/",
  "TransactionTime": "PT11H9M0.6074603S",
  "Comment": null,
  "UserName": "virtual",
  "CustomerItem": {
    "ItemID": 0,
    "ItemCode": null,
    "Description": null,
    "CustomerID": 10004
  },
```

I have done up till UserName, however it is not working with CustomerItem.

Comment: `NSDictionary* customerItem = overallDictionary["CustomerItem"];`

Answer (score 2):

dicionaryName[@"key"][@"key"][@"key"] and so on. If you could supply pretty printed JSON that would be helpful. For parsing use NSJSONSerialization class.

EDIT:

to get the item id and

```
dictionaryName[@"CustomerItem"][@"ItemID"]
```

to get the item code:

```
dictionaryName[@"CustomerItem"][@"ItemCode"]
```

and so on.

Comment: It needs to be pointed out that there is an ItemID in the enclosing dictionary as well.  One would want to retrieve them into differently-named variables.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSDictionary *mainObject = ...

NSString *userName = mainObject[@"UserName"]; // or [mainObject valueForKey:@"UserName"];

NSDictionary *customerItem = mainObject[@"CustomerItem"]; // or [mainObject valueForKey:@"CustomerItem"];

NSNumber *itemID = customerItem[@"ItemID"]; // or [customerItem valueForKey:@"ItemID"];
```